# How to convert a 1 channel image into a 3 channel with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, channel

I have an image that has one channel. I would like duplicate this one channel such that I can get a new image that has the same channel, just duplicated three times. Basically, making a quasi RBG image.

I see some info on how to do this with OpenCV, but not in PIL. It looks easy in Numpy, but again, PIL is different. I don't want to get into the habit of jumping from library to library all the time.

Comment: Switch to using [Imageio](https://imageio.github.io/) - it *makes* Numpy ndarrays.  The docs for [scipy.ndimage.imread](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy-ndimage-imread) even state to switch to Imageio.

Comment: Ughh...then, I'll come across something in Imageio where I'll need to switch to OpenCV, then, I'll come across something in OpenCV where I need to switch to PIL....then it starts again...I'm getting a stomach ache from the computer vision merry-go-round!

Comment: If you can get your data into an ndarray there isn't much you can't do to it. and if other libraries like scipy make it easier to do those things ..... did you look through the docs for PIL and find anything?   Are you using PIL or Pillow?

Comment: One format to rule them all, eh? 
I'm using PIL.

Comment: Just use numpy on its own. You can convert to numpy array using a PIL method, then broadcast the single array into 3 channels, then convert back to a PIL Image object.

Comment: Then I have to deal with swapping axis since PIL and numpy have different indexing systems. So, at least we are down to two different formats...I guess that's a step in the right direction

Comment: This is answered pretty clearly in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way without looking too hard at the docs..

fake image:

```
im = Image.new('P', (16,4), 127)
```

Get the (pixel) size of the single band image; create a new 3-band image of the same size; use `zip` to create pixel tuples from the original; put that into the new image..

```
w, h = im.size
ima = Image.new('RGB', (w,h))
data = zip(im.getdata(), im.getdata(), im.getdata())
ima.putdata(list(data))
```

Or even possibly

```
new = im.convert(mode='RGB')
```

Answer (score 6):

just use:

```
image = Image.open(image_info.path).convert("RGB")
```

can convert both 1-channel and 4-channel to 3-channel

Comment: This is cleaner and more useful than accepted answer. Great for these pesky image AI libs that demand triple channel images.